# Javascript/Jquery - Increase padding percentage of div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

I have a problem that I've spent the better part of half a day trying to solve with no real solution I'm happy with. I have a carousel which contains a placeholder image for a youtube video, and when you click on it the placeholder image is removed and is replaced by the youtube video, but as the aspect ratio of the placeholder image is different from the video, and I need this to work responsively, I need to increase the percentage of the padding of the div these sit in when the user clicks (or taps) on the div.

So, my HTML for this div looks as such:

```
<div class="youtube_video">
<img src="img/video_poster_carousel.jpg" width="986" height="308">
<!-- <iframe width="986" height="555" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Wt_Ruy_ejPY?enablejsapi=1&list=PL027E2B6D9900A88F&showinfo=0&controls=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
/* video */
.youtube_video { position: relative; padding-bottom: 31.65%; height:0;  }
.youtube_video img { position: absolute; display: block; top: 0; left: 0; /*width: 100%; height: 100%;*/ z-index: 20; cursor: pointer; }
.youtube_video:after { content: ""; position: absolute; display: block; 
    background: url(play-button.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
    top: 45%; left: 45%; width: 46px; height: 36px; z-index: 30; cursor: pointer; } 
.youtube_video iframe { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;  }

/* image poster clicked, player class added using js */
.youtube_video.player img { display: none; }
.youtube_video.player:after { display: none; }
```

And the Javascript being used right now:

```
  $(function() { 
    var videos  = $(".youtube_video");

        videos.on("click", function(){
            var elm = $(this),
                conts   = elm.contents(),
                le      = conts.length,
                ifr     = null;

            for(var i = 0; i<le; i++){
              if(conts[i].nodeType == 8) ifr = conts[i].textContent;
            }

            elm.addClass("player").html(ifr);
            elm.off("click");
        });
  });
```

Basically, I need to increase the padding-bottom on .youtube_video from 31.65% to 56.25% (16:9 ratio) upon clicking on the div. I'm probably missing something obvious, but Javascript/jQuery isn't my strongest point. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you just want to set padding-bottom then add `$('.youtube_video').css("padding-bottom", "56.25%")` before `elm.off("click");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your click function?

```
$('.youtube_video').css('padding-bottom','56.25%');
```

[JQuery CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. Thank you. I knew it would be something obvious, and I think I was almost making it deliberately harder for myself. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8u1Ldz2w/)

If you have the width of the **<iframe>** you can allways set its size and animate it with jquery.

```
$('.video-container').animate({
    width:'200px',
    height:'200px',
});
```